# Select a JRadionButton from group and print out an int value

Tags: java, actionlistener, radio-group

I have five RadionButtons with values from 1 to 5. According to my selection i want to print out the value.

```
    JRadioButton rOneStar = new JRadioButton();
    rOneStar.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(1));
    JRadioButton rTwoStars = new JRadioButton();
    rTwoStars.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(2));
    JRadioButton rThreeStar s= new JRadioButton();
    rThreeStars.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(3));
    JRadioButton rFourStars = new JRadioButton();
    rFourStars.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(4));
    JRadioButton rFiveStars = new JRadioButton();
    rFiveStars.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(5));


    // group stars
    ButtonGroup starGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    starGroup.add(rOneStar);
    starGroup.add(rTwoStars);
    starGroup.add(rThreeStars);
    starGroup.add(rFourStars);
    starGroup.add(rFiveStars);
```

Now I have multiple ActionListeners that print out the value. But in my opinion it's way too much code.

```
        rOneStar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                e.getActionCommand();
                 System.out.println(starGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand());
            }
        });
        rTwoStars.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                e.getActionCommand();
                 System.out.println(starGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand());
            }
        });
        ... and so on
```

Can anyone give me a hint please how I can shorten my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you want to do further but with the code snippet given by you, you could refactor a bit by extracting two methods:

```
private JRadioButton createJRadioButton(int x){
    final JRadioButton rXStar = new JRadioButton();
    rXStar.setActionCommand(Integer.toString(x));
    return rXStar;
}

private ActionListener createActionListener(){
 return new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                e.getActionCommand();
                 System.out.println(starGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand());
            }
        };
}
```

This would reduce your code and make it a bit nicer, like so:

```
JRadioButton rOneStar = createJRadioButton(1);
JRadioButton rTwoStars = createJRadioButton(2);
JRadioButton rThreeStar = createJRadioButton(3);
JRadioButton rFourStars = createJRadioButton(4);
JRadioButton rFiveStars = createJRadioButton(5);

// group stars
ButtonGroup starGroup = new ButtonGroup();
starGroup.add(rOneStar);
starGroup.add(rTwoStars);
starGroup.add(rThreeStars);
starGroup.add(rFourStars);
starGroup.add(rFiveStars);

rOneStar.addActionListener(createActionListener());
rTwoStars.addActionListener(createActionListener()); 
rThreeStars.addActionListener(createActionListener());
rFourStars.addActionListener(createActionListener());
rFiveStars.addActionListener(createActionListener());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)